# wpf StateChanged Event is not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

If I'm pressing Win + D, the StateChanged event is not firing, but if the ResizeMode is CanResize,the StateChanged event is firing.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
</Grid>
```

If I hook a messages loop and debug it, I am never in on Win + D with "NoResize"

```
IntPtr mainWindowPtr = new WindowInteropHelper(sender as Window).Handle;
HwndSource mainWindowSrc = HwndSource.FromHwnd(mainWindowPtr);
mainWindowSrc.AddHook(Hook);
```

But if I spy with Microsoft Spy++, there is a WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message on Win + D

What is wrong? And how can I catch this message/event?

Answer (score 1):

Your Application `Window` is *not* being resized when you press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, so there is no reason for the `StateChanged` event to be fired. You can verify this by running your Application and pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to see the `Window` state options. You will notice that the options to Maximise, Minimise and Restore are greyed out, which means that they cannot be selected.

That is because you have set the `ResizeMode` property to `NoResize` and would explain why you get different results when it is set to `CanResize`. So, whatever the operating system does to hide `Window`s when <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is pressed does not involve resizing them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Sheridan. But I'm looking for a working solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Got the same case.

`Window.ResizeMode` is `NoResize` and i am trying to `Show()` and then `Hide()` `Minimized` window programaticaly.

Even if i change the `WindowState` property in code, event has not fired on `Hide()` (but has fired on `Show()` btw).

In my case i fired it by myself and it works for me.

```
public new void Hide()
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            base.Hide();

            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

            base.OnStateChanged(new EventArgs());
        });
    }

    public new void Show()
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            base.Show();

            base.Topmost = true;
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        });
    }
```